# Segfault resulting from strdup and strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I've been assigned a homework from my college professor and I seem to have found some strange behavior of `strtok`

Basically, we have to parse a CSV file for my class, where the number of tokens in the CSV is known and the last element may have extra `","` characters.

An example of a line:

```
Hello,World,This,Is,A lot, of Text
```

Where the tokens should be output as

```
1. Hello
2. World
3. This
4. Is
5. A lot, of Text
```

For this assignment we *MUST* use `strtok`. Because of this I found on some other SOF post that using `strtok` with an empty string (or passing `"\n"` as the second argument) results in reading until the end of the line.  This is perfect for my application since the extra commas always appear in the last element.

I've created this code which works:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_TOKENS 5

const char *line = "Hello,World,This,Is,Text";

char **split_line(const char *line, int num_tokens)
{
    char *copy = strdup(line);

    // Make an array the correct size to hold num_tokens
    char **tokens = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * num_tokens);

    int i = 0;
    for (char *token = strtok(copy, ",\n"); i < NUM_TOKENS; token = strtok(NULL, i < NUM_TOKENS - 1 ? ",\n" : "\n"))
    {
        tokens[i++] = strdup(token);
    }

    free(copy);

    return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    char **tokens = split_line(line, NUM_TOKENS);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TOKENS; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", tokens[i]);
        free(tokens[i]);
    }
}
```

Now this works and should get me full credit but I hate this ternary that shouldn't be needed:

```
token = strtok(NULL, i < NUM_TOKENS - 1 ? ",\n" : "\n");
```

I'd like to replace the method with this version:

```
char **split_line(const char *line, int num_tokens)
{
    char *copy = strdup(line);

    // Make an array the correct size to hold num_tokens
    char **tokens = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * num_tokens);

    int i = 0;
    for (char *token = strtok(copy, ",\n"); i < NUM_TOKENS - 1; token = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
    {
        tokens[i++] = strdup(token);
    }

    tokens[i] = strdup(strtok(NULL, "\n"));

    free(copy);

    return tokens;
}
```

This tickles my fancy much nicer since it is much easier to see that there is a final case. You also get rid of the strange ternary operator.

Sadly though, this segfaults! I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Edit: Add some output examples:

```
[11:56:06] gravypod:test git:(master*) $ ./test_no_fault 
Hello
World
This
Is
Text
[11:56:10] gravypod:test git:(master*) $ ./test_seg_fault 
[1]    3718 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./test_seg_fault
[11:56:14] gravypod:test git:(master*) $
```

Comment: Ah I see the \n confusion now. Using strtok with \n is how you'd parse a whole text file loaded into memory line-by-line. If you're only processing a single line that contains no line breaks itself then it has no magical significance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the return value from `strtok` before you risk passing `NULL` to another function. Your loop is calling `strtok` one more time than you think.

It is more usual to use this return value to control your loop, then you are not at the mercy of your data. As for the delimitors, best to keep it simple and not try anything fancy.

```
char **split_line(const char *line, int num_tokens)
{
    char *copy = strdup(line);
    char **tokens = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * num_tokens);
    int i = 0;
    char *token;
    char delim1[] = ",\r\n";
    char delim2[] = "\r\n";
    char *delim = delim1;                   // start with a comma in the delimiter set

    token = strtok(copy, delim);
    while(token != NULL) {                  // strtok result comtrols the loop
        tokens[i++] = strdup(token);
        if(i == NUM_TOKENS) {
            delim = delim2;                 // change the delimiters
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);    
    }
    free(copy);
    return tokens;
}
```

Note you should also check the return values from `malloc` and `strdup` and free your memory properly

Comment: I'll clean up that memory management. If this is the alternative I'll just stick with my ternary. I think this problem warrants a for loop pattern. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you for the vote. A `for` loop for `strtok` is rather ugly and not idiomatic, and as you have found, troublesome.

Comment: If you're worried about the number of lines here you could cut out all of the delim variables, make the first one ",\n" or ",\r\n" as here, and just put your ternary in the the last strtok line. The advantage with the for loops is that it guarantees you don't overflow the tokens array: the disadvantage is that you don't cope well with inputs with fewer segments. Which is solvable with both approaches but then your calling code needs to accept return values with fewer elements or return allocated empty strings etc.

Comment: I wanted to make the code obvious. I could have used the single delimiter string `",\r\n"` and simply incremented the string pointer when the `','` was no longer required. Please write code plainly and simply. You might have a "fancy" that you want to make some method work, but the overriding concern should be readabilty, and maintainabilty, and the minimum time spent debugging the result of complicated expressions.

Comment: That wasn't my point at all. OP said he wasn't going to use your code because he thought it was too complex so he'd use his ternary, I told him how to use your code with his ternary in fewer lines.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the last loop, you'll get

```
for (char *token = strtok(copy, ",\n"); i < NUM_TOKENS - 1; token = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
```

1. loop body
2. loop increment step, i.e. `token = strtok(NULL, ",\n")` (with the wrong second arg)
3. loop continuation check `i < NUM_TOKENS - 1`

i.e. it has still called `strtok` even though you're now out-of-range. You've also got an off-by-one on your array indices here: you'd want to initialise `i=0` not 1.

You could avoid this by e.g.

- making the initial strtok a special case outside the loop, e.g.

  ```
  int i = 0;
  tokens[i++] = strdup(strtok(copy, ",\n"));
  ```
- then moving the `strtok(NULL, ",\n")` inside the loop

I'm also surprised you want the `\n` there at all, or even need to call the last strtok (wouldn't that already just point to the rest of the string? If you just trying to chop a trailing newline there are easier ways) but I haven't used strtok in years.

(As an aside you're also not freeing the malloced array you store the string pointers in. That said since it's the end of the program at that point that doesn't matter so much.)

Comment: If you look at my question you will see why I need the \n as a final case. Take a look at what needs to be printed out. Look at the "5." output case.

Comment: I understand why no comma but I don't see any newlines in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that [`strtok`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html) identifies a token when it finds *any* of the characters in the delimiter string (the second argument to `strtok()`) - it doesn't try to match the entire delimiter string itself.

Thus, the ternary operator was never needed in the first place - the string will be tokenized based on the occurrence of `,` OR `\n` in the input string, so the following works:

```
for (token = strtok(copy, ",\n"); i < NUM_TOKENS; token = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
{                                                                                                         
    tokens[i++] = strdup(token);                                                                          
}
```

The second example segfaults because it's already tokenized the input to the end of the string by the time it exits the `for` loop. Calling `strtok()` again sets `token` to `NULL`, and the segfault is generated when `strdup()` is called on the `NULL` pointer. Removing the extra call to `strtok` gives the expected results:

```
for (token = strtok(copy, ",\n"); i < NUM_TOKENS - 1; token = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
{                                                                                 
    tokens[i++] = strdup(token);                                                  
}                                                                                 
tokens[i] = strdup(token);
```

Comment: If you look at the question's `5. A lot, of Text` which includes a comma, you will see why the OP wants to change the delimitors.